# ListView in Android switch places

Tags: android, listview

I'm creating an Android app that displays tv-shows on a listview. My shows coming up in the ListView, but they switch places one scrolls.

They are created as costum listview and the class is here:

```
public class CustomListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private static ArrayList<Show> searchArrayList;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private TextView txtTitle, txtPrev, txtNext;

    public CustomListViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Show> results) {
        searchArrayList = results;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, null);
            txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            txtPrev = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.prevNrDate);
            txtNext = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nextNrDate);
        }

        txtTitle.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getTitle());

        txtPrev.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getPrevNr() + " - " + 
                        searchArrayList.get(position).getPrevDate() + "\n" + 
                        searchArrayList.get(position).getPrevTitle());

        txtNext.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getNextNr() + " - " + 
                        searchArrayList.get(position).getNextDate() + "\n" + 
                        searchArrayList.get(position).getNextTitle());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Some one who can help?

//Casper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you were trying to implement a `ViewHolder` to save the extra `findViewById` calls when using recycled views. The problem is that you're storing those views per-adapter instead of per-recycled view. You need to create a separate `ViewHolder` object and store it along with each view. The view's tag is a good place to do this.

Try this:

```
public class CustomListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private static ArrayList<Show> mSearchArrayList;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public CustomListViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Show> results) {
        mSearchArrayList = results;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            holder.prev = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.prevNrDate);
            holder.next = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nextNrDate);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        final Show item = mSearchArrayList.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(item.getTitle());

        holder.prev.setText(item.getPrevNr() + " - " + 
                            item.getPrevDate() + "\n" + 
                            item.getPrevTitle());

        holder.next.setText(item.getNextNr() + " - " + 
                            item.getNextDate() + "\n" + 
                            item.getNextTitle());

        return convertView;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView title;
        public TextView prev;
        public TextView next;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move

```
txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
txtPrev = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.prevNrDate);
txtNext = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nextNrDate);
```

outside the `if(convertView == null)` block.

The views are recycled but you are only setting them when the views get created.

Comment: This works, but the down side to this approach is that you're performing the lookup traversal every time. It's more efficient to store away the results of those lookups for later reuse.

Comment: @adamp Oh I agree. Should definitely use the ViewHolder pattern. Was just pointing out what was wrong with the code he posted.